# How to construct a logic app with 2 required blob container trigger conditions

Tags: azure-logic-apps

My behavior objective for the logic app is to start at a specific time waiting on both (2 different storage accounts) blob containers receiving a "go file" before executing a couple of SQL procedures.

This is what I have so far:

[image: Logic app]

If I receive the DMF trigger before the SAP trigger things work fine, but if the SAP trigger happens before the DMF one then the app doesn't seem to detect the SAP trigger and sits there waiting.

Is there a straight forward way to make the app work regardless of the order the trigger files occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested a few things and the one that work was surprisingly this simple solution. If  I now understand your question correctly, 2 triggers on 2 different storage blob folders.

Using a parallel branch would cause this in both possible ways: 
[image: File added on blob 2 first]

The logic app would only proceed when both triggers had succeeded.
[image: Initialize variable]

Would this work for you?